# easy way to export spotipy id, secret and redirect uri

Tags: python, shell, spotipy

Hi I was wondering if there was an easy way to export the `SPOTIPY_ID`, `SPOTIPY_SECRET`, and `SPOTIPY_REDIRECT_URI` to save time. Currently I am typing it out each time but was wondering if it could be done with shell scripting?

```
#!/bin/bash
export SPOTIPY_CLIENT_ID='xxx'
export SPOTIPY_CLIENT_SECRET='xxx'
export SPOTIPY_REDIRECT_URI='xxx'
```

I've tried running this but when I run the python script using spotipy I get this error:

```
No client_id. Pass it or set a SPOTIPY_CLIENT_ID environment variable.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dotenv`.

Check [this post](https://dev.to/jakewitcher/using-env-files-for-environment-variables-in-python-applications-55a1#:%7E:text=env%20file%20is%20a%20text,potentially%20sensitive%20information%20at%20risk.), for instance.